# Django get_absolute_url and named url with namespace

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i have problem with django's named urls which is included with include keyword. In my main urls.py i have `url(r'^blog/$', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog'))`, in my blog.urls i have `url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', BlogDetailView.as_view(template_name='blog_detail.html'), name='blog_detail')`, and i want to use that named url as return statment for get_absolute_url() function in my model. If i type

```
@models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return('blog_detail', (), {'slug':self.slug})
```

It doesnt work... If i remove inculde statment and put in my url all the blog_detail url, it works like a charm, what can i do to fix?

Thanks in advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not prefixing the namespace. Use the following instead:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return('blog:blog_detail', (), {'slug':self.slug})
```

Comment: it worked, but i had to add also app_name="blog" to the main urls.py Thanks!

Comment: Is this really the correct answer? Namespacing is for allowing multiple instances of an application right? So if a model from that application is referring to the hardcoded namespace, how does that help? I would expect something like `get_current_namespace()` or something.

Comment: @StijndeWitt wondering the same. any outcomings from the last four years? the docs show us a `reverse('polls:index', current_app=self.request.resolver_match.namespace)
` example, but we dont have any request in our `get_absolute_url`?